# Performance - High Context Switch

Tags: performance, jboss, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have an application which exposes a web service on which I am trying to do a load test.

It works for few concurrent users without any issue.
When I increase the user count to 30, I simply get this error in JMeter within 100 milli seconds.

`Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException - Non HTTP response message: Connection reset`

[I thought my JMeter config was wrong - but one of the web application which uses this web-service also failed consistently around that time saying the service was unavailable. So, server itself has some issue].

I checked the web service - application log - No exception & very clean.
CPU, Memory utilization of server is also very normal on the server machine.

However, 'Context Switch' & 'Device Interrupts' are increasing under load.
Context Switch is avg 1500/sec under heavy load. Normally It is 500/Sec.
Is this bad? Is it what makes my application perform badly?  I have no clue to resolve this issue.

Note: It is JBOSS server

Comment: There I would look into your thread locks if there are any under your control. A lot of time spent in context switches could mean many threads contending the same shared resource and trying to enter the same lock (something that can yield worse than single-threaded performance in pathological cases) or that you have too many threads being spawned at once (or both). Understanding the specific device interrupts involved might also help narrow things down.

Comment: Are your users staggered? even by a little bit? Or are all 30 users hitting the server simultaneously? Is that sort of test realistic? If your jboss is running on a linux server, run `dmesg` and look for socket or connection related errors. It seems to me like your server network stack isn't able to handle the burst of new connections coming in.

Comment: @RaGe, thanks for your time & input. Yes, 30 users look normal to me. i have a requirement that the webservice should be capable of processing 1000 requests in a min. with avg 1.2 sec response time for an user, i need to increase the user count to get the throughput i want. rt? [I agree, more users will affect server performance, throughput & might bring it down]

Comment: @RaGe, 30 users not hitting @ the same time. But they hit again and again w/o think time.

Comment: Yes you will have to increase user count to reach your target transaction rate. I would suggest using JMeter's ramp up feature to gradually increase the number of active users. Again, the error message you're seeing suggests the problem is at the network level, at a layer lower than HTTP, probably TCP. My first suspicion would be server side network stack including NIC, buffer sizes, config limits etc. I would look for error messages to help figure out what to try next. Look up TCP/IP tuning for high traffic servers.

Comment: Thanks man for your input. I really appreciate it. I will upvote some of your answers.

Comment: If you immediately slammed your server with 30 simultaneous requests then you likely encouraged the vodka and teetotaler problem.  Take vodka, a thimble and a teetotaler - slow degradation to failure.  Take one bottle and one teetotaler and combine and instant failure.  Ramp up.  Ensure your users are arriving chaotically instead of simultaneously

Comment: @JamesPulley,  I increment 1 user per min. very gradually. Not a stress test

Comment: at what user level does it become unresponsive?  What resource is impinged as validated by your monitors?